# Android SIP Conference call

Tags: android, sip, conference

I want to do a conference call using [Android Sip](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html). Is that possible? Can someone give a working example please. Also are there any limitations of using that library like can it work on 3G or 4G?

Comment: If anyone know anything related to conference, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current Android SIP API does not support creating conferences. However the functionality could be implemented on a SIP Application Server (AS). 
In theory, it would be possible to use FACs (Feature Access Codes) at server side.

Example:
You are in a call with +1234567890 and want to add +1234567890 to the call.
by using `makeAudioCall` API with a supported FAC in the `peerProfileUri`, lets say "tel:*111#+1234567890#+1234567890#" a capable AS could place the second call create a conference.

> Also are there any limitations of using that library like can it work on 3G or 4G?

There are no limitations, it can work on 3G/4G as long as bandwidth for audio is enough. Audio mixing is normally done at server side, so each participant would send/receive audio as in a regular call (no additional streams).

Comment: Thank you so much @Viriatvs.